# Create search dropdown list in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to create a static list of three links as a dropdown when I click in the textarea for search (without typing anything and without autocomplete/suggestions).
The code for the search feature in my header.php is

`<input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('How Can We Help You?'); ?>" name="s" class="search_field" autocomplete="on" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PHP to make your blog more dynamic, as PHP is a server side programming language - it does it's magic before the page loads. If you want an auto-complete/suggestion drop down menu the simplist way is using the jQuery UI. You can read more about that [here](http://jqueryui.com) and read more about the autocomplete functionality [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: Thank you, the autocomplete script could be useful if I can change it to show all of my 3 links directly in a dropdown by default, just on focusing on the searchform - or regardless if the first letter typed is contained in the links or not.

Comment: You can do that by setting minChars to 0 in the options passed into the autocomplete method called on the dropdown menu. You can do a quick search to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way would be to use js to show a custom select box on focus of the search, just tried a couple of ways and something like this might help...

```html
  <input type="search" onfocus="document.getElementById('searchSelect').style.display='block'" />

<select style="display:none;" id="searchSelect"><option><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></option><option><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></option></select>
```